# ZipArchive: Renomear arquivos antes de extrair

Tags: php, zend-framework-2, arquivo-zip

Seguinte galera... 
Eu tenho centenas de arquivos .zip gerados automaticamente. 
Esses arquivos zips não possuem um "padrão", pois são gerados de diversos sistemas diferentes. Portanto, alguns possuem apenas arquivos XML's, outros possuem outros ZIP's dentro com outros XML's e até pastas, por isso não há uma ordem correta dentro desses ZIP's. 
O que eu tô pelejando: extrair todos os XML's de dentro desses ZIP's com nomes únicos, pois é comum que cada zip tenha ZMLs com nomes iguais, porém com conteúdo diferente. Resumindo, é uma extração recursiva garantindo que nenhum arquivo será substituído por conter nome igual.

Eu criei o seguinte código:

```
public function TrataZip($dir)
{
    $tmpupload = './data/tmpuploads/' . session_id() . '/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            $extensao = pathinfo($path);
            if ($extensao['extension'] == 'zip') {
                $zip = new \ZipArchive();
                $zip->open($path);
                $zip->extractTo($dir);
                $zip->close();
                unlink($path);
                return $this->TrataZip($dir);
            } elseif ($extensao['extension'] == 'xml') {
                $stamp = new \DateTime();
                rename($path, $tmpupload . $stamp->format('d-m-Y-H-i-s-') . rand() . "-nfe.xml");
            }
        } else if ($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            return $this->TrataZip($path);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

O código que criei extrai todos os arquivos XML bonitinho e etc. Mas aí a minha dor de cabeça: Se eu fizer o upload de vários ZIP's ao mesmo tempo e por coincidência esses ZIP's possuem arquivos com nome igual, um arquivo irá sobrescrever o outro devido ao nome. Este tem sido meu problema e, por mais que eu tente, nada que use parece funcionar no Zend Framework 2.

Enfim, independende do que contenha dentro dos arquivos ZIP's, sejam pastas, outros tipos de arquivos e etc, eu só preciso de TODOS OS XML's e ter certeza que nenhum deles serão sobrescritos por conta de nomes iguais.

Help por favor

Answer (score 1):

Ok... depois de muito fuçar e quebrar a cabeça, eu encontrei uma "solução" funcional para o meu caso.

**Estou respondendo a própria pergunta pois percebi que muita gente tem esse tipo de problema, então aqui está caso alguém também necessite ou se depare com uma situação semelhante!**

Utilizei a função **Ziparchive::renameIndex** Após abrir o arquivo zip e, posteriormente, extraí-lo com **Ziparchive::extractTo**, que aceita parâmetros e possibilita a extração de arquivos específicos. Dessa forma, não é necessário a "gambiarra" de abrir zip, copiar conteúdo de arquivo e escrever do lado de fora, pois isso torna o processo bizarramente lento. 
Segue abaixo o código com comentários. 
Segue o código:

```
public function TrataZip($dir)
{
    $files = scandir($dir);
    $stamp = new \DateTime();
    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            $extensao = pathinfo($path);
            if ($extensao['extension'] == 'zip') {
                $zip = new \ZipArchive();
                $zip->open($path);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
                    $stat = $zip->statIndex($i);
                    $nome = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
                    $nome_xml = explode('.', $nome);
                    /*
                    *Isso aqui é má prática, o ideal é encontrar a extensão do arquivo pelo mime type, mas funciona bem também...
                    *Aqui localizo arquivos com a extensão de meu interesse, no caso, XML...
                    */
                    if (@$nome_xml[1] == "xml") {
                        //Renomeio primeiro, para garantir que nenhum terá nome semelhante e extraio após isso
                        $zip->renameIndex($i,$stamp->format('d-m-Y-H-i-s-') . rand() . "-nfe.xml");
                        $zip->extractTo($dir, array($zip->getNameIndex($i)));
                    }
                    elseif(@$nome_xml[1] == "zip"){
                        //Se for zip, renomeio também e extraio logo em seguida
                        $zip->renameIndex($i,$stamp->format('d-m-Y-H-i-s-') . rand() . "-nfe.zip");
                        $zip->extractTo($dir, array($zip->getNameIndex($i)));
                    }
                }
                $zip->close();
                unlink($path); //Removo o zip antigo...
                //Chamo novamente e própria função em caso de haver outros zips dentro do diretório
                return $this->TrataZip($dir);
            }
            //Se o upload for um arquivo XML e não ZIP, renomeio também
            elseif ($extensao['extension'] == 'xml') {
                $stamp = new \DateTime();
                rename($path, $dir . $stamp->format('d-m-Y-H-i-s-') . rand() . "-nfe.xml");
            }
        } elseif ($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            //Se contiver pastas, repito até não sobrar mais nada...
            return $this->TrataZip($path);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Adicionei comentários no código pra auxiliar... acho que não resta dúvidas nele.